# Cannot get html content after a load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace the context of a loaded element with the following code:

```
$("#menu1").load("./templates/menu.html");
var str = $("#menu1").html();
alert(str);
str.replace("[number]", "1");
$("#menu1").replaceWith(str);
```

But I always get an empty `str`, the `menu1` gets loaded correctly with the *menu.html* content so I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Can you please try replace with setTimeout function?

Comment: Have you read docs for [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)? The most important thing here is that it is executed asynchronously. Place next code in "complete" callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test the string after the load - the way you have done it, it can be run whilst the load is still going.  Try this:

```
$("#menu1").load("./templates/menu.html", function() {
    var str = $("#menu1").html();

    alert(str);
    str.replace("[number]", "1");
    $("#menu1").replaceWith(str);
});
```

[More information](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#menu1").load("./templates/menu.html", function(){
   //complete
   var str = $("#menu1").html();
});
```

Loading part isn't instant so you are trying to apply `var str = $("#menu1").html();` before `load()` has time to complete

Comment: @Regent there is no point in my example. OP just had it global, so I kept it that way. He might be doing other operations on the str variable later.

Comment: Nope, was just a proof of concept of the problem I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the task in callback function of load:-

For example :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    Hello this is rachit 1 1 1 1.
    <div id="menu1"></div>
    <script>
      $("#menu1").load("index.html", function() {
    var str = $("#menu1").html();

    alert(str);
    str.replace("[number]", "1");
    $("#menu1").replaceWith(str);
});

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qd7cKVfnX2XPfBT0JFHk?p=preview)